# pairwise.t.test in R returning no value

Tags: p-value, bonferroni, r

I am a noob in R, and have been breaking my head for the past three hours over the pairwise.t.test in R. My data frame is structured as given below. My data frame has the age of flight of bees and the duration which they fly for. I want to check the pairwise difference in duration across days.

> head(a3)

```
      age dur.
    1   3  343
    2   2  640
    3   1  333
    4   3  253 
    5   3   66
    6   3  686
```

When I do one-way ANOVA and follow it up with a TukeyHSD, the console prints the values for adjusted p-values.

```
> an3=with(a3, aov(dur.~factor(age)))
> TukeyHSD(an3)
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = dur. ~ factor(age))

$`factor(age)`
             diff           lwr        upr     p adj
2-1    -16.666667 -1215.7557943 1182.42246 1.0000000
3-1   -105.717444 -1158.4831001  947.04821 1.0000000
4-1   -144.603500 -1198.2056799  908.99868 1.0000000
5-1   -194.405800 -1244.3222876  855.51069 1.0000000
6-1   -223.139535 -1273.5866854  827.30762 1.0000000
7-1   -143.568966 -1190.9244371  903.78651 1.0000000
8-1   -208.927536 -1254.8670531  837.01198 1.0000000
9-1   -255.583333 -1304.7863200  793.61965 0.9999999
```

I want to carry out pairwise.t.test with the Bonferroni p-value adjustment on the data frame. When I go ahead and do that, I get the following output.

> pairwise.t.test(a3`$dur.,a3`$age,p.adjust.method='bonf')

```
        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  a3$dur. and a3$age 

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
2  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
3  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
4  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
5  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
6  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
7  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
8  - - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
...
P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

I do not know why I get blanks for all fields, when in all examples I have seen online, the result is a lower triangular matrix. Has anyone faced similar problems? Are there any solutions for the same?

Cheers

P.S. I have tried the example given in R documentation and it seems to work fine. It's not working for my data set though. I have also ensured that the example data and my data are both data frames.

Comment: Although asked in the context of R, this is due to a statistical confusion. It isn't really a coding question. IMO, it is on topic here.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals? What are the variables? How many groups do you have? Etc.

Comment: hi @gung. Thanks for the comment. Could you kindly elaborate on the statistical confusion bit? Sorry if I am being thick

Comment: No problem, can you say more about your situation and your data?

Comment: Hi @gung. I have now updated the info in my text, including my goal and nature of my data. Incidentally, I had initially thought the NA values in my data might have been a problem. After I saw the example in the documentation, I am convinced that it couldn't be the case. the airquality data has multiple NA across all columns.

Comment: I don't see an ID indicator in your dataframe. How many bees do you have? How many measures do you have per bee? How many groups do you have? What is the situation with your NAs, are they censored measurements?

Comment: I don't see any pairing of flight durations in the data frame, so how could a pairwise test be applicable?  Could you explain what things are supposed to be paired and how that pairing is represented in your data?

Comment: @gung, pairwise.t.test performs a t-test between all possible pairs of levels of a factor, not a paired t-test (so no ID variable). It is unclear why that did not work without knowing more about your data. However, you could try testInteractions in the phia package which can do the same thing and may give a more helpful error if it fails. You would use testInteractions(an3, pairwise="age", adjustment="bonf")

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @tomr. I thought this was about trying to apply a paired t-test. Maybe this is an R coding question after all. I'm not actually sure.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. I will definitely try your suggestions later tonight and post the results.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem just now, but realized the common issue was that some of your groups only included one value.  For example, the following results in the same - - table as you saw before.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
             group = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"))
pairwise.t.test(df$x, df$group)

    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  df$x and df$group 

  a b
b - -
c - -
```

However, when you no longer have categories with only one value, the pairwise.t.test works. (In this case, I changed "b" to "a" so that there are now two values in "a" and two in "b".)

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"))
pairwise.t.test(df$x, df$group)

Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  df$x and df$group 

  a      b     
b 0.2583 -     
c 0.0082 0.0391
```